# Using Mod Rewrite to rewrite a url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following format:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/product/ID/CAT/TITLE
```

ID and CAT are both numeric. So, some real examples:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/view/product/1/2/ipod
http://www.mydomain.com/view/product/3/4/40-inch-tv
etc
```

I want to know if I should try to use mod rewrite, and how, or if I should rather fix the PHP to handle the paths correctly. I want to map the above to something like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/CATEGORY/SUB_CATEGORY/TITLE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: afaik you cant `fix the PHP to handle the paths correctly` without mod rewrite for what you want

Comment: sounds like a mod_rewrite case, for sure .. cann you please specify? where would you get CATEGORY and SUB_CATEGORY from? or do you just want to skip the "view/product" part?

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/ [R]
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/$2/ [R]
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/$2/$3/ [R]
>
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&title=$3

in php you can get the variables as you would normally do, also you will need a rule for all variables entered and/or only category or sub-category or you will end up with a 404 when someone tries to access those pages

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your question is not totally clear to me. Going by your examples what do you want your target URL to become from `http://www.mydomain.com/view/product/1/2/ipod`.

Will it be: `http://www.mydomain.com/2/1/ipod` ?

If yes then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/product/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ $2/$1/$3 [L,R,NC]
```